# nhibernate generic repositories with object relationships

Tags: c#, nhibernate, repository

I am new to nhibernate and have been looking at repository patterns. The problem I am having is how should I deal with object relationships especially saving new sub objects with a generic-repository?

Am I right in thinking that the best solution is to create a new instance of a generic-repository of the type of the sub object and use that to save them? (pseudo code below)

```
GenericRepository<Product> genrep1 = new GenericRepository<Product>(session);
Product prod = genrep1.find(1);
Category cat = new Category();
GenericRepository<Category>() genrep2 = new GenericRepository<Category>(session)
genrep2..save(cat);
prod.category = cat;
genrep1.save(prod);
```

Or am I missing something?
Or perhaps there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `Product.category` as `cascade.SaveUpdate` (or some other kind of cascade) in your mapping you only need to save the `Product` object and all child object will be saved (or update) automatically.